# Proving continuity for $2x+1$ at $x=2$ using epsilon/delta

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

**Problem**

Use the epsilon/delta definition of continuity to show that $f(x) = 2x+1$ is continuous at $x=2$.

**My work**

The book shows an example using a similar, linear function, and while I can certainly do the same steps, I have a hard time [groking](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grok) it.

Let $h = x-2$, which gives $x = h+2$.

The allowed error is $|f(x) - f(2)| = |2h| = 2|h| < \varepsilon$ after skipping some steps, and substituting $x = h+2$.

Now comes the part I'm struggling to understand.

To satisfy $2|h| < \varepsilon$, I just need an $h \ \ \mid \ \ |h| < \frac{\varepsilon}2$. Done. Can do that for any $\varepsilon > 0$.

**My actual question**

What exactly is $\delta$ here? I can't fully understand why $h$ was introduced.

As far as I can tell, $|h| = \delta$, but why the extra variable?

Comment: You don't get to choose $h$, so it doesn't make sense to say "I just need *an* $h$...".  The property you're proving has to be true for all $h$ with $h < \delta$, but you do get to choose $\delta$ as long as it's positive.  So you should be saying something more like "I just need to ensure that $|h| < \epsilon/2$, which I can do by choosing $\delta = \epsilon/2$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to find an h here. Just let $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ Then you have that $$|x-2| < \delta \implies |x-2| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} \implies |2x-4| < \epsilon \implies |(2x+1) - 5| < \epsilon. $$
Now, as $f(2) = 5$, we can say that $|x-2| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(2)| < \epsilon$.

So, $\forall \epsilon > 0,  \exists \delta > 0$ such that $|x-2| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(2)| < \epsilon$. Which is the definition of continuity you were looking for.

Comment: That's interesting. I've always been annoyed when people start by saying "let $\delta = \epsilon / 2$" because I'm left with the question "well, where did you get that from, and why are you starting with it?". But if I read your calculation right-to-left, it makes more sense. Wanting $|(2x+1)-5| < \epsilon$, and working back to $|x-2| < \varepsilon / 2$ makes it more understandable.